# Matrix of alternating 1 and -1 elements - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like to know how to create a matrix `n x n` the following order, for example

```
n=3;

 1 -1  1     
-1  1 -1
 1 -1  1

n=4;

 1 -1  1 -1
-1  1 -1  1
 1 -1  1 -1
-1  1 -1  1
```

for every number `n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution involves no arithmetic operations:

```
A = ones(n);
A(1:2:end, 2:2:end) = -1;
A(2:2:end, 1:2:end) = -1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to produce a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of points, then calculate:

```
(-1)^(x+y)  ,
```

where `x` and `y` are the 2D co-ordinate positions inside the grid.  The main intuition behind this approach is when you take -1 and power it to an odd number, you return -1, and if it's an even number, it's +1.  By taking a look at each location in a 2D grid, the parity (odd/even-ness) when you sum the `(x,y)` co-ordinates together alternates between odd and even... assuming integer co-ordinates of course.  You can take advantage of this by taking the sum of each `(x,y)` location, and applying this to the power coefficient with -1 as the base to achieve our alternating matrix you desire.

I was inspired by this approach by considering how the determinant of a matrix is calculated.  Check out Laplace's formula on calculating the determinant here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix

As such:

```
n = 3; %// Define n here
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:n);
A = (-1).^(X+Y)

A =

     1    -1     1
    -1     1    -1
     1    -1     1
```

If you want to show this for `n = 4`:

```
A =

     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     1    -1     1
     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     1    -1     1
```

Comment: Nice! and interesting.

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks :)  I got this idea because this is the main driving force behind calculating the determinant of a matrix.  The even and odd positions constantly flip sign so I figured... why not use that here?

Comment: @Divakar - Right here! :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix

Comment: I am stealing this idea! :)

Comment: Sorry had to do that with `bsxfun`! :)  That's not a crime on SO I hope :)

Comment: @Divakar - Nope.  People get inspired from borrowing other people's ideas all the time :)  Nice work!

Comment: Alight, posted another one, which should be less of hack from your  solution :) Feeling less guilty  now!

Comment: Very clever.  Nice connection to the determinant!

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1**

```
>> n = 4;
>> 1-2*mod(bsxfun(@plus,[1:n]',1:n),2)
ans =
     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     1    -1     1
     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     1    -1     1
```

---

**Approach #2**

This one's a hack from [Ray's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26810427/3293881) -

```
>> n = 4;
>> (-1).^bsxfun(@plus,[1:n]',1:n)
```

Comment: Two good approaches.  I think I like the -1^ approach best.  It's always Ok to borrow ideas by the way.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

[`toeplitz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) works for this:

```
>> n=3;
>> hrow = ones(1,n); hrow(2:2:end)=-1;
>> A = toeplitz(hrow)
A =
     1    -1     1
    -1     1    -1
     1    -1     1

>> n=4; hrow = ones(1,n); hrow(2:2:end)=-1;
>> A = toeplitz(hrow)
A =
     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     1    -1     1
     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     1    -1     1
```

[The link](http://matlabtricks.com/post-31/three-ways-to-generate-a-checkerboard-matrix) that Nemesis gave in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810119/matrix-of-intermittent-1-and-1-elements-matlab/26810230#comment42192885_26810119) to the OP boils down to this:

```
p = mod(1:n, 2);
A = 1-2*bsxfun(@xor, p.', p)
```

That's fine too, and lots faster for big `n`.

Comment: OHHHH toeplitz!  Haven't seen that since my Controls course back in the day.  Nicely done :)

Answer (score 3):

```
cos((0:n-1)*pi)'*cos((0:n-1)*pi)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all solutions, here are two more solutions.

One is related with vector multiplication:

```
p = 1-2*mod(1:n,2);
A = p.'*p;
```

The second one is working with the Kronecker product, but (alas) only if the output size is even:

```
A = kron(ones(n/2), [1 -1;-1 1]);
```